# Errores al compilar una App Mobile con conectividad OFFLINE

Tags: genexus

Tengo una App mobile que no posee ninguna Transactions. Sólo un SDT, procedures, y trabaja grabando y levantando datos del external object "Client Storage" y generando notificaciones locales con el external object "LocalNotificationInfo".  con la siguiente configuracion:

*****Configuracion# 1:************

Panel SD (Main Program = True y Set As Startup Object) ==> tiene la propiedad "Connectivity Support" = Online

Procedure1 ==> tiene la propiedad "Connectivity Support" = Inherit

Procedure2 ==> tiene la propiedad "Connectivity Support" = Inherit

Procedure3 ==> tiene la propiedad "Connectivity Support" = Inherit

Procedure4 ==> tiene la propiedad "Connectivity Support" = Inherit

---

Con esta Configuracion# 1, al presionar F5 o Build All, termina sin errores. Funciona bien.

Ahora si cambio la configuracion a OFFLINE:

*****Configuracion# 2:************

Panel SD (Main Program = True y Set As Startup Object) ==> tiene la propiedad "Connectivity Support" = Offline

Procedure1 ==> tiene la propiedad "Connectivity Support" = Inherit

Procedure2 ==> tiene la propiedad "Connectivity Support" = Inherit

Procedure3 ==> tiene la propiedad "Connectivity Support" = Inherit

Procedure4 ==> tiene la propiedad "Connectivity Support" = Inherit

---

Con esta Configuracion# 2 da errores de compilación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya revisé la configuracion de las Variables de Entorno y las propiedades del IDE de Genexus pero no encuentro donde puede estar el problema para solucionarlo.
Debo configurar alguna nueva Variable de Entorno, actualizarla, ó me falta bajar/instalar algo mas en mi notebook de desarrollo?

a)  JAVA_HOME: tenemos  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101
b)  Path: tenemos   %JAVA_HOME%\bin

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por el error de compilacion parece que no se genero algun Sdt. Intenta un rebuild a ver si lo genera. Si eso no soluciona, envia export (xpz) de tu caso a soporte. Gracias

Comment: Para resolverlo tuve que crear una nueva KB, y a ella le importe los objetos del XPZ que obtuve de la KB original. La nueva KB con los objetos importados, compiló sin errores.